# How do I implement a live-updating preview (e.g. Stack Overflow posts)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I achieve the exact same effect in Stack Overflow that makes the post preview, where the user types in a `<textarea>`, and content is written to a `<div>`?

Comment: You can always have a look at the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a very quick mockup in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/PuWju/). This has **absolutely no security whatsoever**, so you'll want to implement that to avoid script injection and the like.

Comment: Had no idea jsFiddle existed. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Love that site. Incredibly useful. Also check out ReFiddle, for debugging regexes: http://refiddle.com/ :)